# What input does neural network need for making predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a *very* beginner question. I have fitted a model, that predicts a stock price. What input does the neural network need to make a prediction? If I have a batch size of 30, do I need to feed in 29 last known prices?
By the way, here is my code:

```
    # First step, import libraries.
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import h5py

random_seed = 452

# Neural network configuration
num_epochs = 500
num_batch_size = 30
lstm_activation_function = "sigmoid"

df = pd.read_csv("data_dl.csv")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"],unit="s").dt.date
group = df.groupby("date")
Real_Price = group["Close"].mean()
Real_Price = Real_Price[len(Real_Price)-29:]

# Data preprocess
training_set = Real_Price.values
training_set = np.reshape(training_set, (len(training_set), 1))
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler()
training_set = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
X_train = training_set[0:len(training_set)-1]
y_train = training_set[1:len(training_set)]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), 1, 1))

from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("20180302_0340e500b30_s452.h5")

yhat = model.predict_on_batch(X_train)

fname_graph = "pr_e" + str(num_epochs) + "_b" + str(num_batch_size) + ".png"
plt.figure(figsize=(25,15), dpi=80, facecolor="w", edgecolor="k")
ax = plt.gca()  
plt.plot(yhat, color = "red", label = "Price")
plt.title("Price", fontsize=40)

for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_fontsize(18)
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label1.set_fontsize(18)
plt.xlabel("Time", fontsize=40)
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={"size": 25})
plt.savefig(fname_graph, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It needs the same input as your training data. If your training set is 10.000 samples with 50 values each, you would need to provide your model with 50 values to get a prediction, i.e. your input dimension would be (1, 50)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters if I understand you correctly, then I have to input the last sample, and then I'll be able to get a prediction?

Comment: Yes, or any other sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Maximilian wrote in his comment, the input that your network takes for predictions should have the same shape as the input it took during training. In this case, we cant tell for sure what that is, because there's no training going on in your code; it looks like you're loading a model that's already trained with:

```
model = load_model("20180302_0340e500b30_s452.h5")
```

However, the naming of the variables in the following lines suggest that you always use one datapoint (a single value?) at time `t` in order to predict the next value at time `t+1`:

```
X_train = training_set[0:len(training_set)-1]
y_train = training_set[1:len(training_set)]
```

If this kind of code was indeed used during training, then you should also use a similar setup for predictions: provide one number for a point in time `t` as input, get the prediction for the next time step `t+1` as output.

> If I have a batch size of 30, do I need to feed in 29 last known prices?

Using batches is more common during training, when making predictions it's much more common to have a batch size of 1, though it is possible to also make predictions for entire batches at once if you have a large number of new inputs for which you wish to make predictions.

Either way, the answer to your question in this quote is **no**. Batch size refers to the number of input-output pairs you have/want (where input could be a vector of many elements, which I suspect happens to have just a single element in your case). If you have a batch size of 30, that means you provide 30 different input values corresponding to 30 different time steps `[t0, t1, ..., t29]` as inputs all at once, and get 30 different outputs for 30 different matching time steps `[t0 + 1, t1 + 1, ..., t29 + 1]` all at once.

Comment: Sorry, here is my training code: https://pastebin.com/dGVfmEkj. So, if I understood correctly, I have to input a single value into the neural network to get a single value output?

Comment: @DJ_Tth3jtr Yes, my guess about how you did training was correct: both `X_train` and `y_train` are equally-sized arrays of scalars (just numbers), so your network learns to predict one output value given one input value. If your `X_train` had been a matrix for example, then your network would have learned to predict one output value per row of the matrix (where every row contains many numbers = many inputs).

Comment: @DJ_Tth3jtr Since you're using so little input per output, I wouldn't expect very good results by the way. I would expect better results if, for example, you supply a vector of the previous 5 or 10 or 50 or whatever values as input, instead of just one. But if you want to do that you also have to modify your training code.